# Postgres basebackup - cannot execute SQL commands in WAL sender for physical replication

Tags: linux, postgresql, pgpool

Good Morning all,
I have an HA setup consisting of 2 Postgres servers with pgpool on top of them. The setup is working fine.
I am trying to replicate data of this cluster to a third Postgres server(outside the current cluster) using the *pg_basebackup* command for the same. When I provided pg_basebackup with the master Postgres IP it worked fine and data was replicated to the third server.

Now, I am trying to perform the same activity but this time, instead of providing the IP for the master Postgres I am providing the pgpool IP to the pg_basebackup command and received the following errors.

On the master Postgres server logs

```
LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
ERROR:  cannot execute SQL commands in WAL sender for physical replication
```

On the Postgres server from where pg_basebackup is executed

```
pg_basebackup: could not send replication command "SHOW data_directory_mode": FATAL:  Backend throw an error message
DETAIL:  Exiting current session because of an error from backend
HINT:  BACKEND Error: "cannot execute SQL commands in WAL sender for physical replication"
server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
```

Note: Pgpool is configured in a way that all the read/write requests are directed only to the master postgres server and I am using streaming replication with pg_basebackup.

Comment: I have the same issue between barman and pgpool. Do you solve it?